# Go Modules for microservices

Tags: go

I am developing multiple microservices, which require different modules (which shall be available like modules on github, but private)

My first tests with Go were all located within one package, which gets quite messy after some time

I'm coming from the Java side of programming - with loads of packages - which keep stuff clear and clean.

(This also works with public modules like on github.com/xyz/module1 github.com/xyz/module2 github.com/xyz/module3)

I just need this for private modules - how can I do so?

This is what I tried yet:

Directory of my go sources:

```
 C:\my\path\to\go\src\
```

In this dir I have multiple subdirs containing modules (actually more than listed here)

```
my-module1 
my-module2 
my-module3
```

For each folder I called `go mod init` but I get the message that

```
package my-module1/util is not in GOROOT (c:\go\src\my-module1\util)
```

which is obviously right, as my private libraries reside in `C:\my\path\to\go\src\`

Importing packages from github with `go get ...` is working without troubles (those packages will be loaded but copied to `c:\go\src`)

Working with all files in one folder works but is not the desired solution (I need to create multiple microservices therefore I want to be able to create different projects with custom executeables and or tests)

What am I doing wrong?

If more information is needed I will provide it - just let me know what
NOTE: packages without go file in `package main` cannot be installed via `go install`. This system looks pretty confusing to me - as modules cannot be found...

Comment: Make sure you're clear on the difference between a *package* and a *module* - it seems likely that these should be packages in a single module, not separate modules.

Comment: as i can only create one main per package - how do you provide multiple executeables then? (whereat i will have the same problem again - that i cannot refer to my own packages from another module)??

Comment: You can only have one `func main()` in a package, but you can have multiple `main` packages in a module (and this is a common practice). You cannot import a `main` package from another package regardless of whether it's the same or a different module; you just can't import `main` ever.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend reading [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html). You also might find [this article](https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1) helpful, particularly point #4 on organizing `main` packages.

Comment: so in your opinion i should have one module with packages eg for creating barcodes and one for modifying pdf, multiple folders with main() to generate the executables for. i do not get the point for combining completely independent code into one module (if i want to gain a barcode for the pdf it should be possible to include another module)

equivalent in java would be:
module=jar
package=package correct? NOTE: thanks, read both articles

Comment: Based on what you've described, it isn't completely independent code - if it was, you wouldn't be asking about importing. I think module=jar is close but not quite equivalent; Go modules are different from Java jars. [The official wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) has a thorough rundown on the hows and whys of modules.

Comment: sorry, but just because an application uses different modules (importing modules...) it does not mean the modules themself are not independent...

Comment: If one module depends on the other, they are not independent, by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i created a multimodule

means i have a root folder (lets call it `root`) which contains a `go.mod` file
this defines the `root` module

it requires all my submodules
and it replaces the absolute path into a relative.

```
root
 * aa
 * ab
 * bc
```

main gets defined as

```
module root

go 1.15

require (
 root/aa v0.0.0
 root/ab v0.0.0
 root/bc v0.0.0
)

replace (
 root/aa => ./aa
 root/ab => ./ab
 root/bc => ./bc
)
```

all the submodules have a very simple definition (this is equal for all, as long as you do not have any dependencies)

```
module root/aa
```